# Belongs_to not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have this problem:
[image]

And I have this code:

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable  

  def full_name 
    "lalalala"
  end
end
```

status.rb:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @status.user.full_name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content:</strong>
  <%= @status.content %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(@status) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', statuses_path %>
```

What am I missing here? I can't access the full_name method, but I don't know why. I'm new at Ruby-on-Rails so it must be some simple detail that I'm not understanding.
rails version: 4.1.5; ruby version: 2.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to `Marek`'s comment, you'll also want to look at using the [`.delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method, to prevent the [`Law Of Demeter`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (having more than one "point" to call a method):

```
#app/models/status.rb
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   delegate :full_name, to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

This will give you the ability to call:

```
@status.user_full_name
```

---

**Validity**

As `Marek` said, you'll likely not have any `user` object associated to your `status`.

To determine if this is the problem, you'll want to use a [conditional statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) to check if the `user` object actually exists before calling it:

```
<%= @status.user_full_name if @status.user.present? %>
```

This will give you the ability to call the associated `user` object is present

Answer (score 4):

You have all you need in your error message. Your `Status` record doesn't have associated `User` record, so `@status.user` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answer can solve your view issue. But there are many issue you may face because of your current code.

Few things that I found that creating issue:

1st : You are getting `@status.user` to nil. That means your `user_id` column (That must be there) in status not setting properly. So set that first then use solution above to rescue you from error.

2nd : You don't specified any relation in your status model. You should have `has_many :statuses` or `has_one :status` in your user model.

3rd : To make sure you have user_id column properly populated in your status table. try create it like below:

if you have `has_one` relation :

```
@user_object.status.create(status_params)
```

if you have `has_many` relation :

```
@user_object.statuses.create(status_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have User associated with @status

```
<%= @status.user.try(:full_name) %>
```

The above will not raise error when there is no user associated.